# Как удалить из List Частично повторяющиеся объекты

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Есть класс для десериализации:

```
class ActorRow
{
    public long idP { get; set; }
    public string fio { get; set; }
    public int idt { get; set; }
    public string tyt { get; set; }
    public string ExpT { get; set; }
    public string Verificated { get; set; }
}
```

в ходе получения часть объектов этого класса может совпадать. Часть объектов может совпадать по всем свойствам кроме Verificated, а часть объектов вообще может не совпадать.
Полученные объекты хранятся в `var RowA = new List<ActorRow>()`
Вопрос: Как удалить из листа все повторяющиеся и частично повторяющиеся записи?
Под удалением понимаю, что если записи совпадают или частично совпадают, то все повторения и оригинал надо удалить.
Глядя на эту задачу решил **пройти циклично по записям и найти дубли, но такой подход меня не устраивает**, хотелось бы сделать что-нибудь по проще, например LINQ, но опыта не хватает. Я даже не знаю с какой стороны начать.

Comment: Думаете, под капотом linq нет обхода записей? То же самое, что и циклы, просто другой синтаксис. Всё в любом случае упрётся в одно и то же место - вам нужно будет написать функцию bool IsDuplicateRow. В чём вы видите выигрыш? Чем это будет проще?

Comment: В чем разница между "повторяющиеся" и "частично повторяющиеся" записи? И что вообще такое "частично повторяющаяся запись"?

Comment: @AK во-первых надеюсь получить меньше записей в коде, во-вторых надеюсь выиграть в производительности (снижении нагрузки).

Comment: @Anamnian, повторяющаяся - совпадает полностью, частично повторяющаяся - совпадают все свойства кроме Verificated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Переопределим GetHashCode.

```
class ActorRow
{
    public long idP { get; set; }
    public string fio { get; set; }
    public int idt { get; set; }
    public string tyt { get; set; }
    public string ExpT { get; set; }
    public string Verificated { get; set; }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked
        {
            var hashCode = 675286467;
            hashCode = hashCode * idP.GetHashCode();
            hashCode = hashCode * fio.GetHashCode();
            hashCode = hashCode * idt.GetHashCode();
            hashCode = hashCode * tyt.GetHashCode();
            hashCode = hashCode * ExpT.GetHashCode();
            return hashCode;
        }
    }
}
```

Далее просто группируем по хешкоду и фильтруем те которое уникальные, т.е. в 1 экземпляре. Собираем в плоскую коллекцию, старую забываем.

```
var rows = new List<ActorRow>();
rows = rows.GroupBy(r => r.GetHashCode())
    .Where(g => g.Count() == 1)
    .SelectMany(g => g)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: кратенько, и даже использование линк, понятно.

Comment: Переопределяете `GetHashCode`, но не переопределяете `Equals`... не надо так...

Comment: @Anamnian для более краткого примера и в этой задаче equals не нужен.

Comment: Ну ладно, так и запишем.

Answer (score 1):

Как правильно подметил [@AK](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/213987/a-k) вы получите те же циклы при написании `linq-`запросов.

Сделал 2 способами- циклом и Linq'ом.

```
void Main()
{
    var a = new List<ActorRow>{
        new ActorRow { idP = 1, fio = "abc", idt = 1, tyt = "a", ExpT = "b", Verificated = "true" },
        new ActorRow { idP = 2, fio = "abc", idt = 1, tyt = "a", ExpT = "b", Verificated = "false" },
        new ActorRow { idP = 3, fio = "bca", idt = 1, tyt = "a", ExpT = "b", Verificated = "true" },
        new ActorRow { idP = 4, fio = "bas", idt = 1, tyt = "a", ExpT = "b", Verificated = "false" },
        new ActorRow { idP = 1, fio = "abc", idt = 1, tyt = "a", ExpT = "b", Verificated = "true" },
        new ActorRow { idP = 1, fio = "das", idt = 1, tyt = "a", ExpT = "b", Verificated = "false" },
        new ActorRow { idP = 1, fio = "abc", idt = 1, tyt = "a", ExpT = "b", Verificated = "true" },
        new ActorRow { idP = 1, fio = "abc", idt = 1, tyt = "a", ExpT = "b", Verificated = "true" },
    };
    var b = new List<ActorRow>();
    foreach(var el in a){
        var item = b.FirstOrDefault(x => x.idP == el.idP && x.fio == el.fio && x.idt == el.idt && x.tyt == el.tyt && x.ExpT == el.ExpT);
        if(item == null){
            b.Add(el);
        }
        else{
            b.Remove(item);
        }
    }       
    Console.WriteLine(b);


    var c = a.Where(x => !a.Any(el => a.IndexOf(el) != a.IndexOf(x) && x.idP == el.idP && x.fio == el.fio && x.idt == el.idt && x.tyt == el.tyt && x.ExpT == el.ExpT )).Select(x => x).ToList();
    Console.WriteLine(c);
}

// Define other methods and classes here
class ActorRow
{
    public long idP { get; set; }
    public string fio { get; set; }
    public int idt { get; set; }
    public string tyt { get; set; }
    public string ExpT { get; set; }
    public string Verificated { get; set; }
}
```

Вывод:

```
idP fio idt tyt ExpT    Verificated
2 abc 1 a b false 
3 bca 1 a b true 
4 bas 1 a b false 
1 das 1 a b false
```

---

Можно еще попробовать способ который предложил [@tym32167](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/179763/tym32167) в комментариях:

```
var d = a.GroupBy(x => new { x.idP, x.fio, x.idt, x.tyt, x.ExpT }).Where(x => x.Count() == 1).Select(x => x.First()).ToList();
Console.WriteLine(d);
```

Вывод:

```
idP fio idt tyt ExpT Verificated
2 abc 1 a b false 
3 bca 1 a b true 
4 bas 1 a b false 
1 das 1 a b false
```

Comment: Как вы думаете, если сгруппировать последовательность по всем полям, кроме verified, а потом сделать SelectMany  на группах, у которых count ==1,  оно сделает что нужно автору?

Comment: `если записи совпадают или частично совпадают, то все повторения и оригинал надо удалить`

Comment: Не увидел где вы удаляете оригинал

Comment: @tym32167 спасибо за замечание, не сразу заметил.

Comment: Если не трудно, обратите внимание на мое предложение с группировкой. Сам не могу ни потестить, ни ответ написать, еду в отпуск :)

Comment: @tym32167 Да, сейчас попробую, только рабочий вариант с Linq доделаю.

Comment: @tym32167 Да, такое возможно, только в этом случае он обрезает `Verificated`.

Comment: Раз уж вы пользуетесь linqpad - оцените мощь `.Dump()` - и забудьте про `Console.WriteLine`

Comment: Если в варианте с группировкой выбирать не `x.Key`, а `x.First()` - то поле `Verificated` не пропадёт

Comment: @Zufir Спасибо за уточнение, действительно поле присутствует, и что я сразу не додумался First() брать...

Comment: Так я изначально и предлагал это, только вместо first предлагал selectmany, что для групп с одним элементом одно и то же :)

Answer (score 1):

То же самое, что и в ответе @Anamnian просто код почистил:

```
void Main()
{
    var source = new List<ActorRow>{
        new ActorRow { idP = 1, fio = "abc", idt = 1, tyt = "a", ExpT = "b", Verificated = "true" },
        new ActorRow { idP = 2, fio = "abc", idt = 1, tyt = "a", ExpT = "b", Verificated = "false" },
        new ActorRow { idP = 3, fio = "bca", idt = 1, tyt = "a", ExpT = "b", Verificated = "true" },
        new ActorRow { idP = 4, fio = "bas", idt = 1, tyt = "a", ExpT = "b", Verificated = "false" },
        new ActorRow { idP = 1, fio = "abc", idt = 1, tyt = "a", ExpT = "b", Verificated = "true" },
        new ActorRow { idP = 1, fio = "das", idt = 1, tyt = "a", ExpT = "b", Verificated = "false" },
        new ActorRow { idP = 1, fio = "abc", idt = 1, tyt = "a", ExpT = "b", Verificated = "true" },
        new ActorRow { idP = 1, fio = "abc", idt = 1, tyt = "a", ExpT = "b", Verificated = "true" },
    };

    var result = new List<ActorRow>();
    foreach (var el in source)
    {
        if (!result.Any(x => this.IsSemiDup(x, el)))
            result.Add(el);
    }
    result.Dump();
}

// Define other methods and classes here

public bool IsSemiDup(ActorRow a, ActorRow b)
{
    if (a.idP != b.idP)
        return false;

    if (a.fio != b.fio)
        return false;

    if (a.idt != b.idt)
        return false;

    if (a.tyt != b.tyt)
        return false;

    if (a.ExpT != b.ExpT)
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

Публикую код лишь для того, чтобы было видно, что есть варианты более читаемые, чем первый предложенный.

PS И да. Тут можно легко зарыться в тему сравнения по ссылке/значению и более правильно написать процедуру поиска дубликата.